# Is there a way to dynamically chose table in subquery from content of main query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have tables a bit like the following:

GroupText (itemId int, tableName nvarchar, text nvarchar)
1, 'ItemTable1', 'Some text'
2, 'ItemTable2', 'Some text'
3, 'ItemTable2', 'Some text'
4, 'ItemTable3', 'Some text'

ItemTable1 (itemId int, isProposal)
1, 1

ItemTable2 (itemId int, isProposal)
2, 0
3, 1

ItemTable3 (itemId int, isProposal)
4, 0

I'm trying to find a way to select the text column from GroupText, where isProposal is 1 in the ItemTable belonging to the text

I might be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT text
FROM GroupText gt
WHERE
(
 ( 
  gt.tableName = 'ItemTable1' AND
  (
    SELECT COUNT(itemId)
    FROM ItemTable1 tbl1
    WHERE tbl1.itemId = gt.itemId AND tbl1.isProposal = 1
  ) > 0
 ) OR 
 ( 
  gt.tableName = 'ItemTable2' AND
  (
    SELECT COUNT(itemId)
    FROM ItemTable2 tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.itemId = gt.itemId AND tbl2.isProposal = 1
  ) > 0
 ) OR 
...
)
```

But that's not practical as there are 30+ tables

I thought I had a great idea of putting the subquery in a function, where tableName and itemId are parameters

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N'SELECT isProposal FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE itemId = @itemId';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
```

Then use code a bit like this to get the value:

```
SELECT text
FROM GroupText gt
WHERE
 functionName(gt.itemId, gt.tableName) = 1
```

But functions are not allowed to execute sql like this

Views are also not an option as they can't build sql dynamically like this, as far as I know

The only option I can see right now is to split it into two. First load all data from GroupText into a temporary table, then for each item call a more dynamic sql (like what I tried in the function) to see if I should include it in result or not

Is that the best way to accomplish what I'm trying or is there a better way?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Bad design? You could (sub)query all itemtables with union all (`select 'itemtable1' as tbl, fld1, fld2 ... from itemtable1 union all select 'itemtable2' as tbl, fld1, fld2 ... from itemtable2 ...`) and perform any check on that union.

Comment: @jarlh sorry, forgot to mention it is MS SQL Server

Comment: @Arvo Forgot about that option. Is it faster than my plan of splitting it in two and use dynamic sql? It will have to go through 30+ tables. I can try it out

Comment: About performance - you should try. Depend on indexes and whatnot else SQL server optimizer may generate very different query plans, sometimes even exclude unused union parts etc.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Sounds like a good solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @Adagio . . . You should fix your data model.  Your basic problem is 30 tables with the same information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The tables does have more data that is unique for each one of them, but in my current query I have no use for that data. E.g. one table contains boilers (with fields like temperature) and another table with windows (with fields like length and width). In theory it would be possible to just use one table and save the unique data as JSON (I have no need to search in this data, so wouldn't cause any problems). Doing this would help me a lot in other aspects of the project, but this is an old project where that is not an option